# Get user profile details from Google using access token

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api, google-api, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

We have mobile app developed in react native in which we have to implement Google and Facebook login. We have RN libraries using which we will get Facebook and Google user's profile details. But our requirement is like we need to just pass the access token to web api which is developed in asp.net core, and using the access token we have to verify the access token in asp.net core web api and fetch the user's profile details using Facebook or Google Apis.

It is working fine for Facebook api, below is the code for the same

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/") };
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"me?access_token={token}&fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,age_range,birthday,gender,locale,picture");
```

Similarly, when we pass access token(id_token) for google, it is not working, and below is code for the same,

```
var token ="eyJhb.eyJpc....";
var httpClient1 = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/") };
var response1 = await httpClient1.GetAsync($"userinfo?access_token={token}");
```

Can anyone please assist me, how can we verify the access token and fetch the user's profile details?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: any updates on this ? did you found anything ?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify your "id_token" and get some user profile details at the same time by making GET request to the next endpoint:
"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123".

```
var token ="eyJhb.eyJpc....";
var httpClient1 = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/") };
var response1 = await httpClient1.GetAsync($"tokeninfo?id_token={token}");
```

as described in google documentation "https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth" (Calling the tokeninfo endpoint) section.

**However** in case you want to access google api services:
"id_token" is not meant to be used to access google api services, then you will need to have an "access_token" not an "id_token", you can follow the next documentation for that :
"https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2"

Comment: how i can i validate the token using the Secret code ?